# fullcalendar clears events when I go to other moth view

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and I am not using event source, I render all the events by using renderEvent method like following:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        id: obj.Id,
        title: obj.Title,
        start: obj.Start,
        end: obj.End,
        text: obj.Text,
        className: "custom" + colorIndex,
        allDay: obj.AllDay,
        userId: obj.userId
    });
```

But the problem is, like I rendered 5 events in Mar.2011, they are all displayed OK. And then I navigate to Feb.2011 and back, all the 5 events are disappeared.

Does it mean that if I render the events like this, I have to render the events everytime the view is changed?

Best Regards.
Larry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried last night.

If I use event source then the problem is solved.

It seems that if I render the event one by one. They are not kept through view changing.

Comment: They are kept in the clientEvents.  You could access those each time there is a change in the view and save them off somehow, but that would only be per visit to the page.

Answer (score 2):

you gotta use the `stick` parameter of the `renderEvent` function
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

Comment: oh,yeah, this is what I want. Thanks a lot, arshaw!

Comment: Any reason why this isn't the default? Thanks